# DNN DDRMenu: How to use Token [DEPTH]

Tags: dotnetnuke, ddrmenu

I am creating a menu using ULTOKENS in DNN. I want to check the depth of the page so that it only displays the child pages of the current page the user is in. Is it possible to check the Depth of the page using the [DEPTH] TOKEN and how do I go about doing it? Thanks.

```
[>NODE-TOP]
    [?BREADCRUMB]
    [?ENABLED]

    [/?]
    [?NODE]
        [?DEPTH] = 2
            [*>NODE-TIERONE]
        [/?]
        [?DEPTH] = 3
            [*>NODE-TIERTWO]
        [/?]
    [/?] 
    [/?]
[/>]
```

Answer (score 0):

You use NodeSelector to determine which pages are displayed.  For example, NodeSelector="RootChildren" displays children of the currently selected root menu item.  Thare are many other ways tomselect pages.  See the DNN Wiki at dnnsoftware.com.